# how to change a directive variable value in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

List of directive are listed like:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="dashboard" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button class="btn btn-white" ng-click="minim()"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></button>
    <widget-item widget-id="1" widget-type ="chart"></widget-item>
    <widget-item widget-id="2" widget-type ="table"></widget-item>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var dashboard = angular.module("dashboard",['ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate']);
dashboard.controller( 'MyCtrl', function ( $scope,$modal) {
    $scope.on = true;
    $scope.minim = function(){
        $scope.on = !$scope.on;
    };
});
dashboard.directive('widgetItem', ['$compile', function($compile){
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:true,
        template: '<div class="panel"><div class="panel-heading"><div class="mypanel-btn" > <a href="" class="mypanel-minimize"  ng-click="toggle()"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></div></div><div class="panel-body" ng-show="on"></div></div>',
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.on = true;
                scope.toggle = function () {
                   scope.on = !scope.on;
                };
        }
}]);
```

Here I have minimize button for individual directive as well as all directive. Individual minimize button working fine(It's define in directive link). Over all minimize button doesn't work. How do I change directive isolate value from controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use **$broadcast** which will emit event and  dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes.

Then, you can use **$on** to listen some event into your directive.

If i follow your code :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $http) {

    $scope.on = true;

    $scope.minim = function(){
      $scope.on = !$scope.on;
      //send minim event downwards to all child scope
      $scope.$broadcast('minim', $scope.on);
    };

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function widgetItem($compile) {
      return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link:function(scope, element, attrs) {

          //Listen event minim
          scope.$on('minim', function(e, data){
            //Change our scope.on data
            scope.on = data;
          });

          scope.toggle = function () {
             scope.on = !scope.on;
          };
        }
        };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('widgetItem', widgetItem);


})();
```

And then, call your directive :

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button class="btn btn-white" ng-click="minim()"><i class="fa fa-minus-square"></i></button>
    <widget-item widget-id="1" widget-type ="chart"></widget-item>
    <widget-item widget-id="2" widget-type ="table"></widget-item>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use directive with `scope: true`, it means that you new scope is a child of parent scope and you can change whatever you want,because it's not an isolated scope.

if you need more with examples, here is a cool article

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/change-variable-from-outside-of-directive.html